# Scala compilation warning and failure. Warning: This catches all Throwables

Tags: scala

This is a simple scala code for checking prime number.
When I compile at command prompt, I get the following warning. I thought I would care less for warning. But it didn't create the .class files.
Can someone share what this warning means?

warning: This catches all Throwables. If this is  really intended, use `case _ : Throwable` to clear this warning.

```
object PrimeNumber extends App {

        println("11 is prime number : " + checkPrimeNumber(11))
        println("111 is prime number : " + checkPrimeNumber(111))


    //Method for checking prime numbers between 1 and 100
    def checkPrimeNumber(num: Int) = {
     try {
            if (num < 1 || num > 100)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number should be between 1 and 100")
        else
            isPrimeNumber(num)
        } catch {
            case e: IllegalArgumentException => e.printStackTrace()
            case _ => println("Exception has occurred!")
        }
}

//Non Functional Method for finding prime number
def isPrimeNumber(number: Int): Boolean = {
        var i = 2
        while (i <= number / 2) {
            if (number % i == 0) {
            return false
        }
            i += 1
        }
            true
 }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is dangerous to catch `Throwable` in Java, and even more in Scala.
Instead, use this:

`catch { case scala.util.control.NonFatal(e) => // do something }`

See http://www.tzavellas.com/techblog/2010/09/20/catching-throwable-in-scala/